# Adding Category attribute but they are missing

Tags: magento2, category, adminform

I have created 2 category attributes. They are appearing in my eav_attribute table. But I can't see them in the category admin form. I'm under magento 2.4.

## Attribute creation

```
$eavSetup->addAttribute(
    Category::ENTITY,
    'svg',
    [
        'type'         => 'varchar',
        'label'        => 'Category svg',
        'input'        => 'textarea',
        'sort_order'   => 100,
        'visible'      => true,
        'required'     => false,
        'user_defined' => true,
        'default'      => null,
        'global' => ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
        'group' => 'Content'

    ]
);
$eavSetup->addAttribute(
    Category::ENTITY,
    'color',
    [
        'type'         => 'varchar',
        'label'        => 'Background color',
        'input'        => 'text',
        'sort_order'   => 101,
        'visible'      => true,
        'required'     => false,
        'user_defined' => true,
        'default'      => null,
        'global' => ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
        'group' => 'Content'
    ]
);
```

I thought doing that was enough, but digging a little bit I saw we also had to write a custom `view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml`

## category form xml

```
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="content">
        <field name="svg">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">100</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">textarea</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">SVG</item>
                    <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="color">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">101</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">color</item>
                    <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: You code is correct and should show in category form.could you please share full file path ?I just use your code and can see 2 new fields in form

Comment: `app/code/Joy/Category/view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml` where Joy/Category is a new module but I don't think there is something wrong in the path

Comment: file path is also correct, just make sure you module is installed...

Comment: it is otherwise it would not have create the attributes

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue before using `'type' => 'varchar'`, instead of `'varchar'` use `'text'`

Something like:

```
$eavSetup->addAttribute(
    Category::ENTITY,
    'svg',
    [
        'type'         => 'text',
        'length'       => 255,
        'label'        => 'Category svg',
        'input'        => 'textarea',
        'sort_order'   => 100,
        'visible'      => true,
        'required'     => false,
        'user_defined' => true,
        'default'      => null,
        'global' => ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
        'group' => 'Content'

    ]
);

$eavSetup->addAttribute(
    Category::ENTITY,
    'color',
    [
        'type'         => 'text',
        'length'       => 255,
        'label'        => 'Background color',
        'input'        => 'text',
        'sort_order'   => 101,
        'visible'      => true,
        'required'     => false,
        'user_defined' => true,
        'default'      => null,
        'global' => ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
        'group' => 'Content'
    ]
);
```

and try creating a custom fieldset in category_form.xml

```
<fieldset name="custom_fieldset">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom Fieldset</item>
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">300</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <field name="svg">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">svg</item>
                    <item name="prefer" xsi:type="string">toggle</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>

        <field name="color">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">color</item>
                    <item name="prefer" xsi:type="string">toggle</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
</fieldset>
```

If that's not enough
there's the declaration of the setup, that's how i've done it inside the upgrade:

```
$eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
            $eavSetup->addAttribute(
                \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY,
                'color',
                [
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'length' => 255,
                    'label' => 'Color',
                    'input' => 'text',
                    'source' => '',
                    'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                    'visible' => true,
                    'required' => false,
                    'user_defined' => false,
                    'default' => '',
                    'group' => ''
                ]
            );
```

The last thing that could possibly resolve is inside module.xml (Vendor_Module/etc/module.xml) to add the sequence (this way it will have to load Magento_Catalog first, and then your customization)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="1.2.5">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Comment: Same issue with your solution sadly :(

Comment: let's see if that's a problem with the content fieldset, could you please try creating a custom fieldset? I've edited my answer

Comment: Still no change with your product form. Almost like it was totally ignored.

Comment: the last thing i can try is the module.xml, i've edited the last part of the answer

Comment: Already have it ^^ `        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Store" />
            <module name="Magento_Catalog" />
        </sequence>`

Comment: I might have figure it out something, I already have a custom module who defines a category_form.xml. I think this is the file that's taken by the framework instead of mine. Considering the module name is : Rocket_Joy; i guess i should add it in the sequence from my own module.

Comment: yep, let me know

Comment: I don't really understand...actually if I put my code into the already defined file it is working...but if I remove that file my custom file is ignored. So looks like it's more related to the module configuration than the code. I guess I can just put my code into that other file...but...it will stay a mystery...